# Group by query in sql server 2008 help

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this simple Orders table

```
Orders
    -------------
    OrderID
    OrderDesc
    OrderDate
    OrderStatus
    OrderAmount
```

In Sql server in one query how do I get for each Orderdate:
- TotalNumber of orders with orderstatus=1,
- TotalNumber of orders with orderstatus=2

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't worded clearly. You may want to fix this before it gets modded down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OrderDate,
Sum(Case When OrderStatus = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS TotalOrderStatusOne,
Sum(Case When OrderStatus = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS TotalOrderStatusTwo
FRMO Orders
GROUP BY OrderDate
```

will give you what you want if you want it on one row per OrderDate. Gets messy if you have too many values for OrderStatus, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested or anything but have you tried just selecting the count from your groups?

Something like:

```
SELECT Count(OrderStatus) As Amount, OrderDate
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderStatus, OrderDate
HAVING OrderStatus = 2 OR OrderStatus = 1
```

Not sure about the syntax though or if HAVING is used in SQL Server..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am looking for something like this:

OrderDate      Records with OrderStatus =1          Records With OrderStatus =2
1-Aug-09            10                               20
2-Aug-09            20                               10

Thanks

Comment: It's better to edit your question than to add an answer with more details.